What's the most practical way to draw such a thing?
I'm just trying to learn graphical packages (tikz, pgfplots..) and I would like to see how a more expert user would approach such a drawing.


The tkz-euclide package might be worth a look

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you so much! I will check it out

Welcome. // Tikz will do as well (tkz-euclide is built on it). // Are you sure about the orientations of the slits? Will work, but is an unusual orientation.

In tikz.dev look for: A) the tutorials, B) basics: grid, draw, node, C) later tikzlibraries: arrows.neta, angle/s. Use standard latex within the nodes, e.g. for greek, like $\theta$.

@MS-SPO tysm! I wll surely give it a look. What do you mean with "slits"? (sorry, I'm italian) if you're talking about the 2 segments divided by a gap, those are antennas (at least, antennas as drawn by my professor lol) and this is a exercise about electromagnetic fields

Ah, my bad: thought you were in wave optics. However, the principle of interference doesn’t change. // Feel free to to post a new question, showing your achievements and obstacle while approaching your intended drawing. It’s not difficult, but you‘ll learn a new way to „draw“ things. Good luck

I would recommend normal TikZ. In my opinion there are no special places.
How familiar are you with it?
And do you already have a workable approach?

Most practical way is matter of opinion. For example I recommend to use interactive drawing tools for such things like inkscape or geogebra. It is better to draw these images and see the result immediately than to program them using approximation numbers for coordinates and special commands. Using your example: how do you know what angle of \theta in your picture looks best? This is individual feeling which can be optimized only by an interactive tool. Programming this picture needs to guest the theta value, run program, look at result, guest another theta value, run program, ... etc.

You need to know around 5 things about TikZ. 
Then somehow like this:

\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta, bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\definecolor{mybgcolor}{HTML}{F8F6E9}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wTheta{22.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\L{2.575}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, 
>={Triangle[length=0pt 3*2.5,width=0pt 2.5]},
background rectangle/.style={draw=none, fill=mybgcolor}, 
show background rectangle,
]

% 1
\draw[step=0.5, help lines] (-0.2,-0.2) grid (4.2,3.2);

% 2
\draw[red, thick] (1,0.5) coordinate(A1) -- +(\wTheta:\L) coordinate(B1) ;
\draw[red, thick] (1,2) coordinate(A2)  -- +(\wTheta:\L) coordinate(B2) ;

% 3
\draw[red, densely dotted] (A2) -- ($(A1)!(A2)!(B1)$) coordinate(A2s) coordinate[pos=1.35, label=center:](A2ss);

\draw[densely dotted] (A2s) -- (A2ss); 

\draw[densely dotted, shorten >=-1mm] (A1) -- ($(A1)!2.25mm!-90:(B1)$) coordinate(A1s);

\draw[<->] (A1s) -- ($(A2s)!(A1s)!(A2ss)$) node[midway, below, sloped, inner sep=1.5pt]{$\Delta$}; 


% 4
\draw[<->] ([xshift=-6mm]A1) -- ([xshift=-6mm]A2) node[midway, right]{$d$};

% 5a
\tikzset{
pics/mypic/.style={%%
code={
\node[rectangle, draw=none, inner sep=0pt, 
minimum width=1mm, minimum height=10mm, 
rotate=#1,
](s){};
%
\draw[rotate=#1] ([yshift=1mm]s.west)
    -- ([yshift=1mm]s.east) coordinate[label=](P2)
        -- (s.north east) coordinate[label=](Q2); 
\draw[rotate=#1] ([yshift=-1mm]s.west) 
   -- ([yshift=-1mm]s.east)  coordinate[label=](P1)
      -- (s.south east) coordinate[label=](Q1); 
}},%%
}

% 5b
\path[] ([xshift=-0.5mm]A1) pic{mypic={0}};

\draw pic [draw, angle radius=4mm, angle eccentricity=1.35,
"$\theta$", green!66!black, <-,
] {angle =A2s--A1--Q2};

\begin{scope}[decoration={
markings, 
mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[red]{>}}}]
\path[draw=none, postaction=decorate] (P2) -- (Q2);
\end{scope}

% 5c
\path[] ([yshift=-0.5mm]A2) pic{mypic={90}};

\draw pic [draw, angle radius=4mm, angle eccentricity=1.75,
"$\theta'$", blue, <-,
] {angle =Q1--A2--B2};

\begin{scope}[decoration={
markings, 
mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow[red]{>}}}]
\path[draw=none, postaction=decorate] (P1) -- (Q1);
\end{scope}

% 6
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1mm] {right angle =A2--A2s--A1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I think the length delta wasn't 100%. So I took the liberty of drawing another (dotted) guide line and correcting it.

If I'm picky ... it's too long now. See this sketch: https://i.sstatic.net/TM3pNR1J.png

I wasn't sure how long it should be. According to his sketch it could be like mine.
But in the code he learns enough TikZ-gimmicks; he should just adjust it as he needs it.

@€dit: I fixed that too at % 3. So he learns the syntax \draw[densely dotted, shorten >=-1mm] (A1) -- ($(A1)!2.25mm!-90:(B1)$) coordinate(A1s); as well.
`

Thanks. It's just physics: the difference between the two red beams is relevant, expressed in units/multiples of the investigated wavelength. So using the centers as you finally did is physically correct. // In this case the manual sketch was a little immature in this detail.

I think the example in the starting post is very good because it basically contains all the basic TikZ knowledge. Anyone who understands and masters this code can draw anything with it.
